# Unit test Angular service

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine, observable

I'm struggling with testing a service in an Angular project.
The service is pretty small but i can't figure out how to test the observer in the class.

I am trying to test a method of this class. The public methods must do what it promises to do. When I call the 'pop' method, the test fails.
Since the pop method is public and has a Message as return values, this method should return a message after invoke it. The underlying code is less relegant in the case of testing.

The reason the test fails is because the observer is still undefined at that moment. I suggest that the reason is because the callback method is not executed at the moment when i call the pop method in the test, thus the addMessage observer is not intialized yet.

Since I have just started on this project, I am cautious about assumptions about the code.
<s>Does anyone have a suggestion on how I could test this code?</s>

<s>Is it right that the pop method is public or should it be private?</s>

Edit:
The pop method is used by a few other classes an can't be private.
My question is actualy: Is this implementation of this service right?

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
    import { share} from 'rxjs/operators';
    import { Observer } from 'rxjs';
    import { Message } from 'primeng/components/common/api';


    @Injectable()
    export class FeedBackService {
      obsAddMessage: Observable;
      obsClearMessages: Observable;
      /** @internal */
      private clearMessages: Observer;
      private addMessage: Observer;

      /**
       * Creates an instance of FeedBackService.
       */
      constructor() {
        this.obsAddMessage = new Observable(observer => this.addMessage = observer).pipe(share());
        this.obsClearMessages = new Observable(observer => this.clearMessages = observer).pipe(share());
      }


      /**
       * Synchronously create and show a new message instance.
       *
       * @param {(string | Message)} type The type of the message, or a Message object.
       * @param {string=} title The message title.
       * @param {string=} body The message body.
       * @returns {Message}
       *          The newly created Message instance.
       */
      pop( type: string | Message, title?: string, body?: string ): Message {
        const message: any = typeof type === 'string' ? {severity: type, summary: title, detail: body} : type;

        if (!this.addMessage) {
          throw new Error('No Containers have been initialized to receive messages.');
        } else {
          this.addMessage.next(message);
        }
        return message;
      }
    }
```

The Test:

```
    import {Message} from 'primeng/components/common/api';
    import {FeedBackService} from './feedback.service';


    fdescribe('Service: Feedback', () => {

      let feedbackService: FeedBackService;
      const MESSAGE: Message = {severity: 'This is a message', summary: 'Title', detail: 'Body'};
      const SEVERITY = 'severity';
      const SUMMARY = 'summary';
      const DETAIL = 'detail';

      beforeEach(() => {
        feedbackService = new FeedBackService();
      });



      it('#pop should return the message when passing in a message', () => {
        let returnMessage = feedbackService.pop(MESSAGE);
        expect(returnMessage).toEqual(MESSAGE);
      });
    });
```

The Error:

[image]

Comment: If the method were private you wouldn't be able to test it. Keep it public.

Comment: @rrd that's not true and that's dangerous : marking your method as private doesn't prevent side effects. **Some methods** can be ignored when they don't do much, but you should **always** test your code. Finally, you can still test private methods, because Javascript doesn't understand the concept of private members.

Comment: As for the OP, have you read [the documentation about testing](https://angular.io/guide/testing) in its entirety ?

Comment: I'd use a subject instead of newing up an observable like that; see my blog post https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2017/Apr/09/async-angular-data.html and the follow up on testing (note that was pre-`HttpClient`).

Comment: I write the tests on existing code, it can not be changed just like that. I myself would not have written the code in this way either

Comment: @trichetriche Yes i have read all the documentation. I suggest that the method must do what it promises and that is giving a message back. The question is, is this method wrongly failed in the test because the method is wrongly implemented or do I miss something in my test implementation?

Comment: You miss a `service.addMessage = new BehaviorSubject(undefined)` in your test or in your `beforeEach` (as @jonrsharpe suggested). But without it, I think you should use a `[Behavior]Subject` in your component too, which would be cleaner (I think).

Comment: @trichetriche The code that I test is already existing code. The purpose of the tests is to check whether the implementation of the code is good. Since the attribute 'addMessage' is private, it is not a solution (and not possible and also not desirable) to reinitialize the private attributes outside the service. The operation of the service is not relefant to the outside world.

For the sake of clarity, it is existing code that I did not write myself and the code should not be changed in the first instance before it is really clear whether the code has been implemented incorrectly.

Comment: It is a solution and it is possible. And if we're at it, `Observable`s don't have any `next` method to propagate an event : those are the proxies, called `Subject` and `BehaviorSubject` ([check yourself](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kuoa3h?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)). So no, the code hasn't been implemented correctly, and you should change it (in my opinion). If you don't want to listen to advice, I'm fine with it, but you sure won't get an easy solution !

Comment: No next is called on a Observable. the next is called on the Observer. Please read above your latest message about the purpose of the test. Your advice given is irrelevant in this context. Again, the existing code can not be modified at this time and that is not the goal either.

Comment: `private addMessage: Observer<Message>;`  `this.addMessage.next(message);` There is no next calling on an Observable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like any Observable, `obsAddMessage` isn't executed until subscribed to, and therefore as you demonstrated the observer is still undefined if you attempt to push a new value in before subscribing.  The solution is simply to set up a subscribe before calling `feedbackService.pop()`.

I set up a simple [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-q-53628003?file=app%2Ffeedback.service.spec.ts) to show what I mean.  The spec from that Stackblitz is:

```
it('#pop should return the message when passing in a message', () => {
  feedbackService.obsAddMessage.subscribe(message => console.log(message));
  let returnMessage = feedbackService.pop(MESSAGE);
  expect(returnMessage).toEqual(MESSAGE);
});
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, this has solved my problem.
The observer observalbe concept has now become completely clear to me!